# Modeling a Net Core Application Using Clean Arch

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, clean-architecture

Well, I have the following flow in my application:

```
Controller --> *call* --> UseCase --> *call* --> UpdateCustomerGateway
```

UpdateCustomerGateway have one method `updateCustomer(Customer customer)` where Usecase can call database to update the customer.

**Looking to [this image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.cleancoder.com%2Funcle-bob%2F2012%2F08%2F13%2Fthe-clean-architecture.html&psig=AOvVaw3_UBT1W34xkkPe18q_wSYb&ust=1584560482119000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPiC44GiougCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD), my doubt is:**

I have a namespace called ***Entites*** and another called **UseCaseDtos**. This last have Request and Response Dto to be used in communication with useCases. But when I call `UpdateCustomerGateway`* I don't know If I pass the Customer (my entity) or CustomerRequestUseCase (my dto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gateways/repositories usually work with entities. Gateways create entities from data sources and update data sources from entities.